# Javascript: How to copy to clipboard without specific user event

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I am writing a webapp, in which the client needs to copy data to the clipboard as soon as the data is available. The data should be copied as soon as a REST call is made and not by a user event.
Is this possible without a browser plugin? Which permissions do I need to do that?

I only found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard) article which was helpful, but it was for browser extensions only.

So this is the ajax call which is triggered by the server via websockets, and when it succeeds, I want to write to the clipboard:

```
$.ajax({
    url: hosturl + '/get-data?id=' + cookieid
}).then(function(data) {
    // data is of type string
    if (data.type === 'STRING') {
        $('#content-container').html(data.stringData);
        // not working
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(data.stringData);
        // also not working
       $('#content-container').select();
       document.execCommand("copy");
    }
```

Comment: no, I have a web socket connection, and the server triggeres the ajax call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try some hacky ways to get your data copied to clipboard.

One of the methods is to create a temporary element, focus and trigger the action.

```
function copyToClipboard(str) {
  var el = document.createElement('textarea');  // Create a <textarea> element
  el.value = str;                                 // Set its value to the string that you want copied
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');                // Make it readonly to be tamper-proof
  el.style.position = 'absolute';                 
  el.style.left = '-9999px';                      // Move outside the screen to make it invisible
  document.body.appendChild(el);                  // Append the <textarea> element to the HTML document
  var selected =            
    document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0        // Check if there is any content selected previously
      ? document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)     // Store selection if found
      : false;                                    // Mark as false to know no selection existed before
  el.select();                                    // Select the <textarea> content
  document.execCommand('copy');                   // Copy - only works as a result of a user action (e.g. click events)
  document.body.removeChild(el);                  // Remove the <textarea> element
  if (selected) {                                 // If a selection existed before copying
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();    // Unselect everything on the HTML document
    document.getSelection().addRange(selected);   // Restore the original selection
  }
};
```

For other examples you can reference [this article](https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f)

Furthemore there is a new API - `Clipboard API` but it is available only for a few browsers now - [Clipboard API support](https://caniuse.com/#search=clipboard)

Comment: so there is no proper way to ask the user for permission and then copy to the clipboard?

Comment: @AlinaJ this is possible in latest browsers only via `clipboard API` please have a look https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi
Nothing prevents you from creating your own popup that will ask a user for permissions

Comment: This won't workaround the issue: execCommand('copy') needs to be executed from within an user gesture.